# Change color on fragment canvas when clicked from Activity

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin

I am making a children's app where the child can fingerpaint on a book spread as seen below.

[image: Sample Image]

The main view is not an ImageView. Rather, it is a custom view extending from GLSurfaceView to allow a pagecurl animation when flipping pages. In order to make a canvas, when a crayon is clicked, my code launches a fragment with a transparent layout to enable drawing on top of the custom view.

It works for each separate color. But when a new color is clicked, the old lines are removed (because a new fragment is launched) and I can draw again using the new color.

However, the ideal behavior is that the old drawing is retained (using the previous color), and the user should be able to keep on drawing with the new color without the fragment being re-launched.

As a test, I've only used the first 3 colors for now.

In the DrawingFragment, I've actually been able to change the color programmatically from the fragment (to CYAN) by calling the method `changeColor`. However, I still need to get the click event from the Activity that corresponds to each color.

*Main Problems:*

- App should launch the fragment only once on the first instance any
  crayon is clicked.
- App should identify if the fragment is already created, and if so, pass the button click event from Activity to Fragment each time a crayon is clicked.

I have a vague idea that maybe I should use an interface but I've yet to fully understand what this does. I'm pretty new to kotlin and android and any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**Main Activity**

```
class ReadBooksActivity : Activity() {

    var mCurlView: CurlView? = null
    var reading_toolbar : View? = null
    var isUp = false
    var drawColor : Int? = null
    var isDrawing = false


    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.readbooks_layout)

        // Start Page Curl for each page

        mCurlView = findViewById(R.id.curl)
        mCurlView!!.setSizeChangedObserver(SizeChangedObserver())
        mCurlView!!.setCurrentIndex(index)

        var bookId = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0)

        Thread(Runnable {
            fetchbookpages()
            mCurlView!!.setBitmapProvider(BitmapProvider(mBitmaps))
        }).start()


        mCurlView!!.setEnableTouchPressure(true)
        mCurlView!!.set2PagesLandscape(true)
        mCurlView!!.setAllowLastPageCurl(true)


        // Toggle Reading Toolbar

        reading_toolbar = findViewById(R.id.readingtoolbar) as View


        // Enable drawing on View


        tabtools.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            showToolbar()
        })

        tabexit2.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            hideToolbar()
        })

        tabexit.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            onSlideViewButtonClick(reading_toolbar!!)
        })

    }

    fun buttonClicked(view: View) {

        //if (!isDrawing) {

            if (view.id == R.id.crayon_black) {
                drawColor = Color.BLACK
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_blue) {
                drawColor = Color.BLUE
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_green) {
                drawColor = Color.GREEN
            }

            callDrawFragment(drawColor!!)
       // }

       // isDrawing = true
    }

    fun callDrawFragment(drawColor : Int) {

        val mFragment = DrawingFragment.newInstance(drawColor)

        fragmentManager!!
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainreadinglayout, mFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
    }
    }
```

**DrawingFragment**

```
class DrawingFragment: Fragment() {

    var drawColor : Int? = null
    var drawingView : DrawingView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

      val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawing_layout, container, false)

        val relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.draw_layout) as RelativeLayout

        drawColor = arguments.getInt("color")
        var drawingView = DrawingView(activity, drawColor!!)
        relativeLayout.addView(drawingView)
        changeColor(drawingView)

        return view
    }

    fun changeColor(view: DrawingView) {
        var currentPaint = Paint()
        currentPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN)
        currentPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        currentPaint.isDither = true
        currentPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        currentPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        currentPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        currentPaint.strokeWidth = 10f
        view.setPaint(currentPaint)
    }

    companion object {

        fun newInstance(color: Int): DrawingFragment {

            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("color", color)
            val fragment = DrawingFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**DrawingView**

```
class DrawingView(context: Context, color : Int) : View(context) {

    var mPaint: Paint? = null
    val mPath: Path

    init {
        mPaint = Paint()
        mPaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
        mPaint!!.isDither = true
        mPaint!!.color = color
        mPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mPaint!!.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        mPaint!!.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mPaint!!.strokeWidth = 10f
        mPath = Path()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    }

    fun setPaint(mPaint: Paint) {
        this.mPaint = mPaint
        return
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        when (event.action) {

            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> mPath.moveTo(event.x, event.y)

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                mPath.lineTo(event.x, event.y)
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by referencing the activity's buttons from the fragment.

```
    var btn_black = (getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.crayon_black) as ImageView
    var btn_blue = (getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.crayon_blue) as ImageView
    var btn_green = (getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.crayon_green) as ImageView
```

And then setting the onclick listeners in the fragment

```
btn_black.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            changeColor(drawingView, Color.BLACK)
        })
btn_blue.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            changeColor(drawingView, Color.BLUE)
        })
btn_green.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            changeColor(drawingView, Color.GREEN)
        })
```

And then re-setting the onclicklisteners on the activity on backpressed. I also had a `booleanTag` to indicate if the fragment is up or not.

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        setColorOnClickListeners()
        booleanTag = "false"
        crayon_black.setTag(booleanTag)
        if (mCurlView!!.getIsUp()) {
            slideDown(reading_toolbar!!)
            mCurlView!!.setIsUp(!isUp)
        }

        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

The setcolorOnClicklistener() is as follows:

```
fun setColorOnClickListeners() {
        crayon_black.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            buttonClicked(crayon_black)
        })
        crayon_blue.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            buttonClicked(crayon_blue)
        })
// etc...
}
```

buttonClicked:

```
fun buttonClicked(view: View) {

        booleanTag = crayon_black.tag as String

        if (booleanTag == "false") {

            if (view.id == R.id.crayon_black) {
                drawColor = Color.BLACK
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_blue) {
                drawColor = Color.BLUE
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_green) {
                drawColor = Color.GREEN
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_orange) {
                drawColor = Color.parseColor("#FFA500")
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_pink) {
                drawColor = Color.parseColor("#ec5db8")
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_red) {
                drawColor = Color.RED
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_violet) {
                drawColor = Color.parseColor("#8862ba")
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_white) {
                drawColor = Color.WHITE
            } else if (view.id == R.id.crayon_yellow) {
                drawColor = Color.YELLOW
            }


            callDrawFragment(drawColor!!)
            booleanTag = "true"
            crayon_black.setTag(booleanTag)
        }

    }
```

Still need to handle some things on the DrawingView for the color change but this solved most of my problems.